# What are the legal file names in a Jekyll post title?

Tags: jekyll

I'm working on a script that publishes Jekyll posts from a variety of sources and am wondering what characters would render correctly as the title.

For instance, I'm reasonably sure that a title like `2022-10-09-#post.md` would not really work, because `#` would be seen as an anchor.  I'm also pretty sure `2022-10-09-post?.md` would have troubles, because of the `?`.

I'm unsure if Jekyll would still publish it, or escape it's links, etc.

I'd like to know what characters Jekyll will not allow in a post title, and how Jekyll will treat characters that are legal file names but not legal urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required filename format for posts is

```
YEAR-MONTH-DAY-title.MARKUP
```

where `YEAR_MONTH_DAY` is in YYYY-MM-DD format, and `MARKUP` is typically `.md` (or any extension you indicate as Markdown using the [`markdown_ext` option](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/default/), default value `markdown,mkdown,mkdn,mkd,md`).

If you don't manually set a permalink in the frontmatter of a post, it'll default to what the [global `permalink` setting](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#global) indicates. The default is `date`, which is a shorthand for `/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title:output_ext`, where `:title` is

> Title from the document’s filename. May be overridden via the document’s `slug` front matter. Preserves case from the source.

though it ignores characters such as `#`.

In other words, the default settings should be able to handle any filename you throw at them, as long as they're in the format above; you can change the result with global `permalink` settings, and override with `slug` frontmatter.

Comment: Can you give a reference why "The required filename format for posts is YYYY-MM-DD"？

Comment: @JingnanJia *[Creating Posts](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#creating-posts)* in the docs, and the [regular expression in the source code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/58a1f62b2349bb477fc9999c40331cecdca577d8/lib/jekyll/document.rb#L15). [This release note](https://jekyllrb.com/news/2017/03/02/jekyll-3-4-1-released/) talks about how that regular expression was changed a few times.